# Newbie syntax issue: error: expected ';' before ')' token

Tags: c

On both for loops (ie:  for(len... and for(wid... ), I receive the same error message:

error: expected ';' before ')' token

```
void
init(void)
{
    //fills board up with numbers
    int tile = (d*d - 1);
    int len = 0;
    int wid = 0;

    for(len < d; len++)
        {
            for(wid < d; wid++)
                {
                    board[len][wid] = tile;
                    tile--;
                }
        }
}
```

Sorry to ask a similar question as before, but I'm a very confused Newbie!

Comment: You're missing a parameter in the for-loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every for-loop needs to have its 3 parts (initialization, test, update) and if you don't have one or more of them, you still have to supply the two `;`, so

```
for(len < d; len++)
    ^
    |
```

should really be

```
    |
    v
for(;len < d; len++)
```

and the same for the other for-loop in your function.

For instance, this is how you would set up an *infinite* loop using `for`:

```
for(;;)
```

where all parts are skipped, but the two semi-colons are still required.

Perhaps this is [tutorial/reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm) on the for-loop is helpful as a review/reference.

Comment: Aha!  Now it all makes sense!  Thanks again, Levon!

Answer (score 5):

In general, a for loop has three parts:

```
for (initialization; check; update) { ... }
```

In your code, you are missing the initialization section.
You are missing a semi colon in your for loops to denote that you don't need an initialization clause (since you do it above):

```
void
init(void)
{
//fills board up with numbers
int tile = (d*d - 1);
int len = 0;
int wid = 0;

for(;len < d; len++)
    {
        for(;wid < d; wid++)
            {
                board[len][wid] = tile;
                tile--;
            }
    }
```

}